# Use ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity using existing database (different dbcontext)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am stuck in my project, is it possible to use different table or existing table in identity feature of MVC5? if yes then please guide me how to do this, I tried so many links but unfortunately not getting it.

Is Simple Membership possible in MVC5?

Comment: You may need to create your own implementation. check [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/25/asp-net-core-identity.aspx) and related articles from Scott

Comment: Check this screen cast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM